# How Do I Configure the SharePoint 2010 Security Token Service for Use By Another Web Application?

Tags: certificate, security-token-service, sso, token

I am trying to configure the SharePoint Security Token Service on SharePoint 2010 so that another non-SharePoint web application can use SharePoint for authentication (SSO).  The only instructions I have found are on this TechNet article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee731989.aspx.  However, it isn't complete and I have questions.

On step 5, it asks for a certificate file.  What certificate?

On step 7, it sets the realm to the computer name I am running the command on.  If this is a load-balanced environment, do I replace it with the URL that is being load balanced or just use the computer name?

On step 8, it has "FederationPassive" in the SignInUrl.  Is that automatically setup when I create the SharePoint web application for this or is this something I will need to setup.

On step 9, it has "-ClaimsMappings $map1[,$map2..]".  These variables were never defined and thus fails because they are null.  What am I supposed to do here?

I am not concerned with the portion of getting the other application to consume the authentication provided by SharePoint STS as that is being setup by someone else.  I just need to get the service configured on my end so that it can be utilized by the third-party.

Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone have a better tutorial on this than what is on TechNet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint does not perform authentication. What you are trying to do is not possible. The page you reference is for configuring SharePoint web applications.

Microsoft's single sign-on approach is based on ADFS2.0. I recommend you deploy ADFS and configure SharePoint and your other application to both delegate authentication to it.

Comment: This is indeed the case.  After working with Microsoft Support it was indicated that SharePoint can only be the Relying Party (RP) and not the Issuing Party (IP).